# Unable to make jquery AJAX POST in Non IE browsers

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, vb.net, http-post

I have a service that accepts multiple parameters and schedules a job. Some parameters might be too lengthy , hence I decided to go with a POST request. 
The service definition is below:

```
<WebInvoke(Method:="POST", UriTemplate:="scheduleJob?JobDateTime={JobDateTime}&JobName={JobName}&TestCases={TestCases}&IDs={IDs}&UserName={UserName}", ResponseFormat:=WebMessageFormat.Json)>

Function ScheduleJob(ByVal JobDateTime As String, ByVal JobName As String, ByVal TestCases As String, ByVal IDs As String, ByVal UserName As String) As String
```

The jQuery call is :

```
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                crossDomain: true,
                url: svcUrl + "jobDateTime={" + jobDateTime + "}jobName={" + jobName + "}TestCases={" + TestCases + "}IDs={" + IDs+ "} + UserName={" + UserName + "}",                        
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                processData: true,
                success: function (data) {
                    alert("success...");
                },
                error: function (xhr) {
                    alert(xhr.responseText);
                }
            });
```

On checking through fiddler I found that the request sent by IE browser sends POST in the headers, but when I use Mozilla or Chrome the OPTIONS header seem to get appended to the request.

I read some posts and did some modifications to my asp.net also:

```
 If HttpContext.Current.Request.HttpMethod = "OPTIONS" Then 
            HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST,GET")
            HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "172800")
            HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
End If
```

but nothing seem to work. If I mock the same request with just "POST" in fiddler then things seem cool. The only issue is how do I get rid of the "OPTIONS"?

I get a 405 response code for the OPTIONS request. The header is:

```
OPTIONS http://localhost:60403/TaskScheduler.svc/scheduleJob?jobDateTime={12/31/2014%2016:25}jobName={}TestCases={format,localeFormat,_toFormattedString,}Ids={0,}%20+%20UserName={abcd} HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:60403
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:34.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/34.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Origin: http://localhost:54249
Access-Control-Request-Method: POST
Access-Control-Request-Headers: content-type
Connection: keep-alive
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
```

Any other suggestion is much appreciated.

Comment: the `options` request is a browser preflight request to check the response headers before continuing with full request

Comment: Hello @charlietfl, I have updated my question with the header and my response code is just a 405. Any suggestion as to how I should handle this?

Comment: doesn't seem to have the all important `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header. I don't work in asp but it seems the `Addheader` code you have isn't working

Comment: So which part requires a change now? The service or my ASP.NET code. I have mentioned added to code to allow `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` in my  `Application_BeginRequest`. Not sure if I am missing anything out. Any pointers @charlietfl

Comment: see if this helps  http://enable-cors.org/ Section for ASP shows things you don't seem to have and a nuget package

Comment: looks like a crossdomain issue when making calls using ajax